# Как сделать на select2 возможность набрать вариант текстом?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Как сделать чтобы пользователь мог сам вводить свои варианты в select2? Чтобы вместо

> no matches found

можно было набрать текстом свой вариант?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У этого плагина есть волшебная опция `tags` (см. https://select2.github.io/options.html#tags). Она позволяет использовать пользовательские значения "как есть".

Пример:

```
$('select').select2({tags: true});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e1hjz7cw/